# What does msck stands for in Msck repair command

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Hive Msck repair command is used to repair partitions, but what is full form of MSCK.

I already tried to find in hive doc's but hard luck.

Answer (score 57):

Similar to how `fsck`stands for [filesystem consistency check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck), `msck` is Hive's **m**eta**s**tore consistency check.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis

Answer (score 16):

It's metastore consistency check

Comment: Thanks a lot Manish